# Workaround to define a method on an interface in Go

Tags: go, inheritance, polymorphism

In a large project I need to use Go to define several types, taking advantage of struct embedding.
However, sometimes I'd like to define a method *on an interface* to avoid duplicating the methods. I know that Go does not allow this, but what would be the best workaround?

Here is a [minimum reproducible example](https://go.dev/play/p/SBBZ_Bj4lsm) with the explanation:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type vehicle struct {
    make  string
    model string
}

type car struct {
    *vehicle
    bootSpace float64
}

type motorbike struct {
    *vehicle
    maxSpeed float64
}

func (c *car) run() {
    fmt.Println("Running the car.")
}

func (m *motorbike) run() {
    fmt.Println("Running the motorbike.")
}

type runner interface {
    run()
}

// I don't want to pass the runner as a parameter.
func Start(r runner) {
    r.run()
}

// I'd like to avoid double-defining the same method here...
func (c *car) start() {
    c.run()
}

// ... and here.
func (m *motorbike) start() {
    m.run()
}

// This raises "invalid receiver type runner (pointer or interface type)".
//func (r runner) startMethod() {
//  r.run()
//}

func main() {
    a := motorbike{}
    b := car{}

    Start(&a) // I don't want to do this.
    Start(&b)

    a.start() // This is what I'd like to do. But with a single method definition.
    b.start() 
}
```

As you can see, I am defining the same method twice with the same code (only that the signature is different) to allow to be called as method and to avoid exposing a `Start()` function.
Any elegant alternative out there?

Cheers.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're looking for something that would be an interface default method in Java. There's nothing like this in Go.

Comment: I don't mean this in a bad way, but this sounds like you are coming from C++ or Java and are new to Go. You sound exactly like me ten years ago, that is why I recognize it ;-) Try learning more about Go, write code, make yourself famililar with the standard library and idiomatic Go code. No such situation occurs in the real world. At the beginning I also thought that Go was missing some OOP feature at times. But it does not, because OOP features are not essential to programming. The structural typing and interfaces in Go work really great in practice and you will love it, I promise :-D

Comment: @gonutz Thanks for the heads up. I like Go but I still miss a few features from the classic OOP, as I could organise larger programs in a clearer way.

Comment: BTW the above situation does occur in the real world